# using javascript to pass value from a child to parent window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a value from a child pop up to a parent page through setting element attributes (in this case value) using windows.opener. The script on the child pop up is:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
    {
      echo "<script>
      window.opener.document.getElementByName('garage_details[]').value = document.getElementsByName('garage_description[]').value;
      window.opener.document.getElementByName('garage_cost[]').value = document.getElementsByName('garage_cost[]').value;
      self.close();
      </script>";
     }
 ?>
```

The popup doesnt close when the submit is posted so i am guessing there is an error in how i am equating the values

Comment: Maybe you should just use AJAX, sending a JSON via [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP/) or simply via `json_encode`.

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByName returns an html node collection and you treat it as a single element. You need to select the first element of the set. (note you need to make the change in two places in your code.)

```
document.getElementsByName('garage_description[]')[0].value; 
                                                  ^^^
```

If you are expecting multiple inputs with values, you need to loop through the array-like collection.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding the index ([0]) to test just one set of values but it passes empty values to the parent window

Comment: Removed the square braces in the names to treat value as single input and adjusted element names/id's accordingly but an 'undefined' error is returned